# Oracle equivalent for SQL Server INSERTED and DELETED tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, triggers

I am in the process of migrating a SQL Server database to Oracle, where I have to convert SQL Server procedure which uses special tables called `INSERTED` and `DELETED` in SQL Server.

As per my understanding these tables hold copies the data of last inserted/deleted records.
(find the msdn article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Are there any similar tables in Oracle to achieve this..?  Please advise.

UPDATE:

Thanks for your answers and comments ,I think I need to explain the situation some more. Here is the full story to understand the real scenario;

- Data base contains tables and shadow tables (shadow has an additional column).
- When a table is updated same changes should be recorded in relevant shadow table with some additional data.
- For this purpose they are having triggers for each table (these triggers copy data to relevant shadow table).
- The above mentioned procedure generates these triggers dynamically for each and every table.
- Now the real problem is I don't have the knowledge about the columns as triggers are dynamically generated for each table.
- Basically I can’t get value like: NEW.col_1 or: OLD.col_1 as APC mentioned. Can I.?

Or else I have to write all those triggers manually using prefixes: NEW and: OLD rather than trying to generate them dynamically.

I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a statement level trigger and a row level trigger? You usually don't need the `inserted` or `deleted` "tables" in Oracle. Use a row level trigger and manipulate the column values directly using `new` and `old` records.

Comment: Not sure why people think this is a DBA question.  Triggers are definitely in the programmer's bailiwick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and comments. here is the complete solution to my problem.If some one meet the exact problem this will help.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CreateTrackingTriggers
(
-- take the target table and shadow user as agruments
v_TableName IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
v_ShadowUser IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'SHADOW_USER' 
)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER -- grant permission to create triggers
AS
v_TriggerName NVARCHAR2(500);
v_ColList NVARCHAR2(2000);
v_ColList_shadow NVARCHAR2(2000);
v_SQLCommand VARCHAR2(4000);
v_ColName NVARCHAR2(500);
v_ColSize NUMBER(10,0);
v_Prefix NVARCHAR2(500);
v_count  NUMBER(1,0);

BEGIN

DECLARE
  -- define a cursor to get the columns of the target table. order by COLUMN_ID is important
  CURSOR Cols
  IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME , CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH  FROM USER_TAB_COLS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME =  upper(v_TableName) order by COLUMN_ID;
  -- define a cursor to get the columns of the target shadow table order by COLUMN_ID is important
  CURSOR Shadow_Cols
  IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME , CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH  FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME =  upper(v_TableName) and upper(owner)=upper(v_ShadowUser) order by COLUMN_ID;

BEGIN
  -- generate the trigger name for target table
  v_TriggerName := 'TRG_' || upper(v_TableName) || '_Track' ;

  -- check v_count , determine whether shdow table exist if not handle it
  select count(*) into v_count from all_tables where table_name = upper(v_TableName) and owner = upper(v_ShadowUser);

 -- iterate the cursor. generating column names prefixing  ':new.'

  OPEN Cols;
  FETCH Cols INTO v_ColName,v_ColSize;
 WHILE Cols%FOUND 
  LOOP 

     BEGIN
           IF v_ColList IS NULL THEN
             v_ColList :=  ':new.'||v_ColName ;
           ELSE
             v_ColList := v_ColList || ',' || ':new.'||v_ColName;
           END IF;

        FETCH Cols INTO v_ColName,v_ColSize;
     END;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE Cols;

  -- iterate the cursor. get the shadow table columns

  OPEN Shadow_Cols;
  FETCH Shadow_Cols INTO v_ColName,v_ColSize;

 WHILE Shadow_Cols%FOUND 
  LOOP 

     BEGIN

           IF v_ColList_shadow IS NULL THEN
             v_ColList_shadow := v_ColName;
           ELSE
             v_ColList_shadow := v_ColList_shadow || ',' || v_ColName;
           END IF;

        FETCH Shadow_Cols INTO v_ColName,v_ColSize;
     END;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE Shadow_Cols;

-- create trigger command. This will generate the trigger that dupilicates target   table's data into shdow table
v_SQLCommand := 'CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER '||v_TriggerName||'
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON '||upper(v_TableName)||'
REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE    
  ErrorCode NUMBER(19,0);
BEGIN

 -- v_ColList_shadow : shdow table column list
 -- v_ColList : target table column list with :new prefixed 
 INSERT INTO '|| v_ShadowUser ||'.'||upper(v_TableName)||'('||v_ColList_shadow||') values    ('||v_ColList||');
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN ErrorCode := SQLCODE;
 END;';

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQLCommand;
 END;
END;
```

Answer (score 7):

Oracle triggers use pseudo-records rather than special tables.  That is, instead of tables we can access the values of individual columns.

We distinguish pseudo-records in the affected table from records in (other) tables by using the prefixes `:NEW` and `:OLD` .  Oracle allows us to declare our own names for these, but there is really no good reason for abandoning the standard.

Which column values can we access?

```
Action       :OLD                :NEW
------       ----                ----
INSERTING    n/a                 Inserted value
UPDATING     Superseded value    Amended value
DELETING     Deleted value       n/a
```

You will see that `:OLD` is the same as the MSSQL table `DELETED` and `:NEW` is the same as  table `INSERTED`

So, to trigger a business rule check when a certain column is updated:

```
create or replace trigger t23_bus_check_trg 
     before update on t23
     for each row
begin
     if :NEW.col_1 != :OLD.col_1 then
         check_this(:NEW.col_1 , :OLD.col_1);
     end if;
end t23_bus_check_trg;
```

There's a whole chapter on records in the PL/SQL Reference.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955).

Comment: Thanks APC , I reached the solution following your guidance.

Answer (score 4):

There are many differences between Sql Server triggers and Oracle triggers. In Oracle, you can declare statement level or row level triggers. Sql Server only has statement level. In Oracle, you can declare before triggers or after triggers. Sql Server only has after triggers.

If you're going to be working with Oracle, although later versions have the [compound trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005), get used to working with row level triggers. There you have the pseudo row designation of :old and :new, kinda like Deleted and Inserted except it's just the one row of data. It's like being in a cursor loop, something you can do in Sql Server, but cursor perform so poorly in Sql Server, developers go to great lengths to avoid them. They are commonly used in Oracle.

The general rule of thumb is this: if you need to examine the data and possibly alter it before it goes to the table, use a "before" trigger. If you want to perform an audit or logging procedure, use an "after" trigger.

The page I linked to above gives a lot of technical details, but it is absolutely atrocious at giving usable examples. For that, just google "oracle trigger tutorial" and you should get lots of handy, easy-to-learn-from examples.

Comment: SQL Server does have `instead of` triggers also which I assume fulfill a similar role to before triggers.

Comment: Both Oracle and Sql Server have `instead of` triggers on views. And they work the same way as table triggers -- Oracle being "for each row" (:old, :new) and Sql Server being "for each statement" (deleted, inserted). I'm a big advocate of using views as often as it is sensible to do so. One of the benefits for Sql Server is that a "covering" view provides the ability to implement a "before" trigger on the underlying table(s).

Comment: You can create instead of triggers on both tables and views in SQL Server.